# (Chrome on Win10) Why "Open as window" checkbox disappeared when creating shortcut of a page

Tags: google-chrome

I just got a new PC. One of the first things I do after installing Chrome is to create shortcuts of Gmail and Google Calendar etc as a stand-alone window and pin to task bar. I do it by clicking ☰ -> More Tools -> Create Shortcut.

However, I found the "Open as Window" checkbox is missing. No idea why. This makes the shortcut not a stand-alone window, which'll stack with the Chrome icon, which is not the desired outcome. How can I resolve this? Thanks!!
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the time being (Oct 2018), the answer is:

1. Create the shortcut in the way you mentioned in your question
2. Open chrome://apps
3. Right-click the newly appeared app and choose "Open as window", then click the app to run it
4. Pin to taskbar while it's open, if you want to
5. If you did 4, you can now safely delete the new shortcut on the desktop, but don't delete the new app in chrome://apps

Source:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/chrome/q3yliRThPPs/I0wPe7EnAAAJ

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution: while it has been indeed removed from the new shortcut dialogue, the "open in window" option has been implemented as a toggle in the Chrome Apps (chrome://apps) page, visible when right clicking an app (shortcut, as it were).

Comment: It is indeed a solution, because I can pin the opened Chrome App to task bar, so they eventually become the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to have a shortcut on the desktop.  Right clicking and setting to open in a window from inside Chrome will also make the shortcut on the desktop open in a new Window as well.